# How to make a random array generator that consists of 1's and 0's, with length taken from user

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am trying to get an array that consists 1's and 0's with a length determined after it has been ran. "arr1.length" is taken from user beforehand.

```
private double[] arrayGen(int A) {
        double[] arr1 = new double[A];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            arr1[i] = (Math.random());
        }
```

this is what i tried so far, it is generating random "double"s, and I can't make it generate 1's and 0's randomly.

Thank you for your help.

John

Comment: Well, I'd personally use `java.util.Random` instead of using `Math` - but all of this *can* be done by calling `Math.random()`. Hint: that returns a `double` between 0 and 1. Think about how to go from a `double` between 0 and 1 to a `double` which is 0 *or* 1.

Comment: (It's not clear why you're using `double` for a value which can only be 0 or 1, mind you...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you want to use `double`.  What about

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Random r = new Random();

    int[] values = new int[10];

    for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
        values[i] = r.nextInt(2);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
}
```

Output

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: `nextInt(2)` will never return 2, so `% 2` is useless.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Oops.  Good catch.  Corrected

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
arr1[i] = (Math.random());
```

to

```
arr1[i] = (Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want integer valued doubles, it may be simpler to generate integers and convert them to double.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayGen(20)));
  }

  private static Random rand = new Random();

  private static double[] arrayGen(int A) {
    double[] arr1 = new double[A];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
      arr1[i] = rand.nextInt(2);
    }
    return arr1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace

```
arr1[i] = (Math.random());
```

with

```
arr1[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
```

ps: you don't need to cast to int if you change "double[] arr1 = new double[A];" to "int[] arr1 = new int[A];"

Answer (score 0):

You are making a call to Math.random(), which returns a random double between 0 and 1. Instead do:

```
Random rand = new Random();
double zeroOne = (double) rand.nextInt(2);
```

rand.nextInt(2); will return 0 or 1 randomly, it is important to remeber that rand.nextInt(value) returns a random number between 0 and the value, but will never return the value itself, it is only 0 up to the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication6;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Ali
 */
public class JavaApplication6 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] anArray;
        anArray = new int[sc.nextInt()];
        for(int i=0;i<anArray.length;i++)
        {
            anArray[i]= randInt(0,1);
        }
       for(int i=0;i<anArray.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(anArray[i]);
        }

    }


    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

    // NOTE: Usually this should be a field rather than a method
    // variable so that it is not re-seeded every call.
    Random rand = new Random();

    // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
    // so add 1 to make it inclusive
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}
}
```